# Good practice of ui:remove in JSF

Tags: jsf-2.2

We use a lot of `ui:remove` in our xhtml (a lot in loop also) to leave some informative comments (not to comment out some code). Saying in that, I was wondering if there is a good reason to use this if it's not to comment out code?

Since I'm working on JSF component tree optimisation in our project, I was wondering if using `ui:remove` add a component in the JSF component tree? If so, I'd use classic `<!-- -->` tags

Comment: Thank you BalusC, we already define this constant to true, but my question is, does `ui:remove` behave like `ui:fragment` for example? It's probably a silly question, but since it's a ui tag handler, I see it as a component then

Comment: We use ui:remove` to leave simple comment like `<ui:remove>If it's not true, it's false then </ui:remove>`. Well, that's the point, I'm not sure why they did that :) But if it can relieve the JSF component tree, I'll change that

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I just tried, using `ui:remove` does not add component into JSF component tree